# How can I convert a Google Tag Manager's Initial Traffic Source cookie values to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, google-tag-manager

I have installed a 'cookie creating' code for Google Tag Manager, using some third party code from UTMZ Cookie Replicator. It sets a cookie and starts collecting the initial traffic source for a user visiting a website. My website is https://www.palmerstonmoving.ca.

The cookie name is `InitialTrafficSource`, and the value returned is

```
utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)
```

How can I get the string values returned by the cookie and convert it to some sort of PHP code, for example:

```
$utmcsr= 'direct',
$utmcmd= 'none',
$utmccn= 'not set',
```

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways to do it and I wonder why you didn't even try one (using basic string functions for instance).

With basic functions:

```
$str = 'utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)';

$result = [];

foreach (explode('|', $str) as $item) {
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $item);
    $result[$key] = trim($val, '()');
}

print_r($result);
```

---

A way that splits the string on `|` and that uses a formatted string to extract the key/value for each item:

```
$str = 'utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)';

$format = '%[^=]=(%[^)])';
$result = [];

foreach (explode('|', $str) as $v) {
    [$key, $result[$key]] = sscanf($v, $format);
}

print_r($result);
```

---

The same written in a functional way:

```
$result = array_reduce(explode('|', $str), function ($c, $i) {
    [$key, $c[$key]] = sscanf($i, '%[^=]=(%[^)]');
    return $c;
}, []);
```

---

With a regex:

```
$str = 'utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)';

preg_match_all('~ (?<key> [^|=]+ ) = \( (?<val> [^)]* ) \) ~x', $str, $matches);

$result = array_combine($matches['key'], $matches['val']);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: The result of the code is: ```Array ( [utmcsr] => direct [utmcmd] => none [utmccn] => not set )```  It is not clear how to get the values from the array, since it prints out the entire created array, but How could I get the values of the array individually?